# Blender shows transparent .png with bloom when rendering but there isnt bloom when I view it with a photo editor

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I am trying to render something with bloom and a transparent background but nothing has worked! I do have the .png with RGBA and blender shows when rendering that there is bloom on the png with a transparent background although when I check it with a photo editing software there is no bloom! When I render it with a black/non-transparent background there is bloom. I have also tried using compositing the bloom in blender and it hasnt worked either. I am using the Blender 3.0 release and the EEVEE rendering engine.

Help would be very appreciated!

[image: The bloom isnt super visible but still there, this is what blender shows when rendering.]

[image: What my photo editing software shows, there is no bloom.]

[image: What blender shows when rendering with a black background]

Comment: there are some tricks to keep the bloom (in the Compositor) but it's not a simple button activation

Comment: Hi :). PNGs don't support both transparent and emissive pixels. For compositing render with EXR. Or render it on a non-transparent background ;)

Comment: @moonboots Can you please show me how to keep the bloom in the compositor? I have tried multiple tricks in the compositor but none have worked.

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi, I tried rendering with EXR but the bloom still wasn't there. I am also making this asset for game that only supports .PNGS and if this asset is rendered with a non-tranparent background some things will not be visible, thanks!

Comment: There are some tutorials on how to do it but I don't know what's the best method

Comment: @moonboots Can you give me any method? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You'll find some methods on youtube, you need to test them, I don't know what's the best, maybe someone will tell: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+bloom+transparency